# How can I iterate this list over a loop? I am a beginner and python is my first language

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, iterable

### Zybooks Instructions

List data_list contains integers read from input, representing a sequence of data values. For each index i of data_list from 1 through the second-to-last index:

The element at index i is a hunch if the element is greater than both the preceding element and the following element.
If the element at index i is a hunch, then output 'Hunch: ', followed by the preceding element, the current element, and the following element, separating each element by a space.

### Example

Ex: If the input is 12 14 72 52, then the output is:

- Sequence: [12, 14, 72, 52]
- Hunch: 14 72 52

### Zybooks code

```
tokens = input().split()

data_list = []
for token in tokens:
    data_list.append(int(token))

print(f'Sequence: {data_list}')
```

### My Code to complete zybooks code

```
for i, data in enumerate(data_list[1: -2]):
    if data_list[i] > data_list[i - 1] and data_list[i] > data_list[i + 1]:
        print(f"Hunch: {data_list[i - 1]} {data_list[i]} {data_list[i + 1]}")
```

### The output with 12, 14, 72, 52##

- Sequence: [12, 14, 72, 52]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with more details. You should put your code here directly instead of a link.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: **DO NOT** use screenshots for plain text. They are hard to read and we can't copy/paste the text in the image. Copy/paste your code into the question surrounded by lines that consist of three backticks for format the code as a "literal" block of text.

Comment: Slice notation can be thought of as `[from : up_to_but_not_including]`. For example, `[1,2,3][-1] == 3` and `[1,2,3][:-1] == [1,2]`. So what you wanted to do is `enumerate(data_list[1:-1])`.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate` always starts counting at zero unless given `start` parameter, so after you slice the list, the index is not representing the original position

Since you're not using the `data` variable, just use range

```
for i in range(1, len(data_list) - 1):
    if data_list[i - 1] < data_list[i] > data_list[i + 1] :
        print("Hunch: " + ' '.join(tokens[i-1:i+2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter input way, and four solutions.

```py
seq = list(map(int, input().split()))

for a, b, c in zip(seq, seq[1:], seq[2:]):
    if a < b > c:
        print('Hunch:', a, b, c)

a, b = seq[:2]
for c in seq[2:]:
    if a < b > c:
        print('Hunch:', a, b, c)
    a, b = b, c

a = b = None
for c in seq:
    if None is not a < b > c:
        print('Hunch:', a, b, c)
    a, b = b, c

b = float('nan')
for c in seq:
    if c < b > a:
        print('Hunch:', a, b, c)
    a, b = b, c
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rZLNSsQwFIVBd3mKAy7aQBQaFCWoKxeufAHpIlNTGsgkcZKC-ipuutGNb-TTeDOtAwNuFC_kh3OT853FfX2Pz3kIfprextwfX3weHCbziCs4m3K91rG2PgtYH8dc85MUnaWTc8b6sIEWWAl01MaLjTX9FKDtvlHtfJGq5YqByvbQuMQK1-hmpVTckH1d3Y6-G1Qlvg3J_sG4nT2OcGOcyQZ5MGsUMl3gzVNGCm7MNnjGymsKXrBKttt822RLjj_FKM3Ftwh7sYhYZFp3wZs93o5VOrAJPuR_5Ba5d0HTV699xX9mdwtP_543z8IyEtNHI9Gc4lziTM7SFw)

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned in your question about how many sets of huches will be there in the list.
i.e just one set of hunches or more than one set of hunches.
Assuming that the list will have multiple sets or hunches hunches, I'he given the solution.
You can modify the code according to your requirement. Understand how to use the f-string and change the code accordingly.

```
l = [12, 14, 72, 52, 22, 78, 33] 
hunches = []

# Index based iteration till the last but one element
for i in range(1,len(l)-1):

    #if the number is greater than both previous and next number, make a list
    if l[i-1] < l[i] > l[i + 1]:
        sub = f'{l[i-1]} {l[i]} {l[i+1]}'

        # append this list to the list hunches
        hunches.append(sub)

print(f'Hunches: {hunches}') #Output: Hunches: ['14 72 52', '22 78 33']
```

Comment: You crash on the same input that I already showed.

Comment: And your output format is wrong, better read the specification again.

Comment: @no comment, Thank you. I've edited my answer now. As I have programmed for multiple hunches, Now I've made a slight change in the output format. But OP can understand and change the output-format

Comment: You still crash on `l = [1,2,3]`. And why do you write extra code just to get the wrong format? Instead of less code and getting it right...

Comment: Sorry. Got it and corrected. Regarding format: The OP has given one hunch per list. But it doesn't mean that the number of hunches should be limited to one per list. In that case, we should write in a format suitable for multiple hunches. Here the format is meant for understanding purpose only. Once the OP understands how to format, the OP can modify the code according his required format.

Comment: edited now. Pl check

Comment: Still wrong on the other end, of course, so for `l = [3, 2, 1]` you're hallucinating a hunch that doesn't exist.

Comment: Should be okay now I guess. Pl check.

Comment: Yeah, now it's the same as OneCricketeer's, except for the wrong and bad list name, the wrong output format, achieved by too much code, and the missed opportunity for operator chaining.

Comment: Thank you. Corrected operator chaining. I got used to write without operator chaining,  Since you pointed out, I came to know that operator chaining is a better way of writing code. Thanks for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257242/discussion-between-suramuthu-r-and-no-comment).

Answer (score -1):

## Define a list

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

## Iterate over the list using a for loop

for item in my_list:
print(item)  # This will print each item in the list on a new line

Answer (score -1):

For the core part of your code to run reliably you really need to do some input validation.

I suggest:

```
while data := input("Enter at least 3 integers or press <Return> to exit: "):
    try:
        if len(nlist := list(map(int, data.split()))) < 3:
            print("\aNot enough values")
        else:
            for a, b, c in zip(nlist, nlist[1:], nlist[2:]):
                if a < b > c:
                    print("Hunch:", a, b, c)
                    break
            else:
                print("No hunch found")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"\a{e}")
```